# How do you revert pandas pivot table back to original shape?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I took this dataframe

```
    name            amf L1  L2  L3
0   CpG_Island_1    0.0 a   1   x
1   CpG_Island_2    NaN a   1   x
2   CpG_Island_3    NaN a   1   x
3   CpG_Island_4    NaN a   1   x
4   CpG_Island_5    NaN a   1   x
```

and created a pivot table with 3-level index:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='amf',index='name',columns=['L1','L2','L3'])

L1                  a
L2                  1
L3                  x           y           z
name            
CpG_Island_1        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
CpG_Island_10       1.000000    NaN         0.866667
CpG_Island_100      0.973684    0.938776    1.000000
CpG_Island_1000     0.555556    0.369427    0.444444
CpG_Island_10000    0.953488    0.941176    1.000000
```

This is the shape I need it for `df.dropna()`. But after dropping `NaN`s how do I revert it back to the original shape?

Answer (score 2):

Check `unstack`

```
out = df.set_index(['L1','L2','L3','name']).unstack([0,1,2])
Out[43]: 
              amf
L1              a
L2              1
L3              x
name             
CpG_Island_1  0.0
CpG_Island_2  NaN
CpG_Island_3  NaN
CpG_Island_4  NaN
CpG_Island_5  NaN
```

Comment: KeyError: "None of ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'name'] are in the columns"

Comment: @jklausJ are they columns ? can you show df.columns ?

Comment: MultiIndex([('a', '1', 'x'),
            ('a', '1', 'y'),
            ('a', '1', 'z')],
           names=['L1', 'L2', 'L3'])

Comment: @jklaus so your first df is what we have and 2nd is what we want ?

Comment: No I want to turn the 2nd one back into the 1st

Comment: just edited the post to include command creating the pivot table

Comment: @jklaus df.stack([1,2,3]).reset_index()

Comment: Voila! Had to use [0,1,2] rather than [1,2,3] but it worked. Thanks so much!